# how to put the pictures boxes in an array of pictures boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

All i want to do is to save my pictures boxes in an array to work on them later,
i made a solution to get these pictures boxes but its soo muchhh big and im pretty sure **theres a way to do it easier** and thats what i want it

```
public PictureBox[] getboxes()
        {
            PictureBox[] boxes = new PictureBox[]{pictureBox1,pictureBox2,pictureBox3,pictureBox4,pictureBox5,pictureBox6,pictureBox7,pictureBox8,pictureBox9,pictureBox10,pictureBox20,pictureBox19,pictureBox18,pictureBox17,pictureBox16,pictureBox15,pictureBox14,pictureBox13,pictureBox12,pictureBox11,
            pictureBox40,pictureBox39,pictureBox38,pictureBox37,pictureBox36,pictureBox35,pictureBox34,pictureBox33,pictureBox32,pictureBox31,pictureBox30,pictureBox29,pictureBox28,pictureBox27,pictureBox26,pictureBox25,pictureBox24,pictureBox23,pictureBox22,pictureBox21,
            pictureBox60,pictureBox59,pictureBox58,pictureBox57,pictureBox56,pictureBox55,pictureBox54,pictureBox53,pictureBox52,pictureBox51,pictureBox70,pictureBox69,pictureBox68,pictureBox67,pictureBox66,pictureBox65,pictureBox64,pictureBox63,pictureBox62,pictureBox61,
            pictureBox80,pictureBox79,pictureBox78,pictureBox77,pictureBox76,pictureBox75,pictureBox74,pictureBox73,pictureBox72,pictureBox71,pictureBox50,pictureBox49,pictureBox48,pictureBox47,pictureBox46,pictureBox45,pictureBox44,pictureBox43,pictureBox42,pictureBox41,
            pictureBox90,pictureBox89,pictureBox88,pictureBox87,pictureBox86,pictureBox85,pictureBox84,pictureBox83,pictureBox82,pictureBox81,pictureBox100,pictureBox99,pictureBox98,pictureBox97,pictureBox96,pictureBox95,pictureBox94,pictureBox93,pictureBox92,pictureBox91};
            return boxes;
        }
```

as u can see this is soo much big

plz any help to make this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every .Net control has a property Controls, which allows to access to its children.

So if all your picture box are in the same container, let's say a Panel "panel1", to retrieve every picturebox you can use :

```
foreach(var ctl in panel1.Controls)
{
   var box = ctl as PictureBox;

   if(box != null)
   {
       // Do what you want : add to an array, get the picture...
   }
}
```

To fill an array with all picture boxes :

```
List<PictureBox> pboxes = new List<PictureBox>();

foreach(var ctl in panel1.Controls)
{
   var box = ctl as PictureBox;

   if(box != null)
   {
       pboxes.Add(box);
   }
}

// pboxes now contains all PB. You can call "AsArray()" LINQ method on it to get an array rather than a List.
```

Comment: the var box is an array of pictureBox after your code?

Comment: No. It's a single picture box, contained in the Controls collection like I explained. I'll make an edit to fill an array with all boxes if you prefer.